# How to populate multiple js-data resources in one request

Tags: jsdata, js-data-angular

I have an AngularJS app that I am converting to use js-data. If I have a REST interface that returns a JSON object in this format

```
{
  data: {
    id: 1,
    name: Test,
    dept: 2
  },
  related: {
    DeptList: [
      { Id: 1, Name: Dept1 },
      { Id: 2, Name: Dept2 },
      { Id: 3, Name: Dept3 }
    ]
  }
}
```

how do I go about extracting *related.DeptList* and injecting it into js-data? I have a deserialize function that can return the data object, but can't see how to extract the related data.

Answer (score 0):

In JSData 2.x, one approach is to iterate over the `relationList` field of the `Resource` passed to `deserialize`, and move relations from your `related` field over into their expected position.

Here is a plunker that demonstrates: https://plnkr.co/edit/suesxw?p=preview

The code in that plunker is pretty general, but there probably some missed edge cases and improvements that can be made to better fit your use case.

Here is a slightly different example based on the new JSData v3 beta: https://plnkr.co/edit/IZJa6jP4cxySlbyRFYF3

Comment: Thanks @jdobry, that's perfect for a hasMany relationship. I wasn't clear enough, sorry. The record in question is a user, so the relationship is a hasOne. I thought I'd be able to reference DS from inside deserialize, so I can just say DS.inject(relatedData) but I don't know how to reference a related resource from the resource itself.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to achieve `DS.inject(def.localField, relatedData)`

Comment: No, you're right ... your solution works for hasOne relationships too. Perfect, thank you very much.